# SSIS Package last run date in a variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My SSIS package has an execute SQL task which has a query that needs a datetime filter at runtime.

The value of this filter is supposed to be the last datetime in which the package ran successfully.

What is the standard/optimal methodology to retrieve, persist and use this lastrun datetime?

Comment: Yeah, esp. at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733136/asp-net-web-api-logging-and-tracing -- the guy spent a bunch of time on that answer, even answered your follow-up questions... 5 people in the community up-voted it... what's stopping you from giving him credit?

Comment: Accepted Answer. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that kind of thing, I have a "config" table in the database to store the value. Then this can be read and updated each time the package runs. You could also use a text file, but that is not as secure.

Edit:

I achieve this by invoking a SQL Task at the end of the Package that calls a stored procedure. This SP accepts a bit parameter indicating success (1) or failure (0). The SP uses GetDate() to record the time that the Proc ran (which is when the Package finishes).

[image]

Comment: What variable/query do you use to retrieve the last successful run time? I do see [System::StartTime] but how to insert it only on success?

Comment: Thanks! But how do you find that if package execution was a success overall or a failure?

Comment: My `LoadExtractFiles` data flow has a success line and a failure line. On the success line, I call the SP and pass 1. On the failure line, I call the SP and pass 0. As to the definition of success, that naturally is specific to each package.

Answer (score 0):

As DeanOC posted, I always have a step in my package that stores this kind of stuff.  It can be as simple as a `insert select current timestamp...` kind of thing. or it may be the max of a timestamp column in the data I'm processing, so that next run I can filter by `...> StoredMaxTimestamp`.